# How do I apply a regression model to my data with categorical variables and interactions?

Tags: multiple-regression, categorical-data, interaction, interpretation, continuous-data

I feel crazy stupid for not knowing this but how do I apply a multiple regression model to my data when I have categorical variables, interactions between continuous and categorical variables, and interactions between categorical variables?

[image: ![enter image description here]

Is this how I would apply the equation to Sample 1?

```
40 * 0.88580 + 2 * 0.31485 + 3.5 * 0.74682 + 0.63089 * 40 * 2 + 0.05942 + 0.78578 * 40
```

Edited to update image for clarity

Comment: Your interaction term between A and "Treatment" is confusing since you have 3 levels of Treatment. Did you find the interaction term to be of the same value for every combination of A and Treatment?

Comment: No - sorry that is confusing. I edited the image to clarify. Initially, I only provided the interaction term between A and Untreated because that was what I used in the example.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in Excel?

Comment: I will eventually do this in R but am trying to understand the concept and put the example into Excel to post on here

Comment: Looks like you’ve applied all the terms correctly